# Is it possible to hide URL trail?

Tags: asp.net, iis, dotnetnuke, url-rewrite-module

Problem is simple, I have a web site `www.mydomain.com` which have other links to other pages (in the same site) like `www.mydomain.com/some/directory/some_page.asp`. I would like to know if it's possible to hide the second part and show only  the `www.mydomain.com`.
I'm using DotNetNuke, IIS web server.
Is it possible to do this with the url_rewrite module?

Comment: If your exact requirement is _"I want the browser's address bar to at all times display `www.mydomain.com` and that exact URI only"_, then use an iframe. You don't want this though.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want all the URLs to show up in the browser as just the domain? the only way to do this would be to use an Iframe, which is a TERRIBLE idea. It means that no one can copy and paste your URLs to send to their friends, and if they just get the URL anyway because they know how to use a browser users will see the full path anyway.

The url_rewrite module won't do what you're after either. It can rewrite one URL to another, e.g. instead of www.mydomain.com/mypage.asp you could have www.mydomain.com/mypage. But you couldn't map ALL of your pages to just the root domain (think about it, how would it know which of your pages to serve up for that URL).

This is something people used to ask for back in the 90's. It was a bad idea then, and it's an even worse idea now.